# what is the difference between android service and web service

Tags: android, service, web

Is there any difference between Android's Service and a web service? Or both are similar concepts? If I want to connect to an online database from my Android phone then should I use an Android Service or a Web Service?

Comment: This is so trivial, just google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android services and webservices are totally different from each other.

1. Android services are used for doing background processing whereas webservices are used to get and send responses from/to a server.
2. Services run in the background whereas webservices are used to get data.
3. Android services are an android internal part whereas a weservice is a concept that we can apply every where eg: in iPhone also in black-Barry or other languages or platforms
4. See [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more information about services and for webservices, see [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp)

Comment: I have heard that bound service is used for the Remote Procedure Calling. How different it is from the web service?

Comment: i haven't idea about bound service but if you get data from database you need to implement webservices.webservices concept base on parser. there are many parser available like SAX parser, DOM parser,Json parser ets depend on your webservices